# Full-text searching in Symfony 2 and Propel 1.6

Tags: symfony, propel, symfony-2.3

How can i use full-text filters in symfony 2 using Propel 1.6 (propel bundle 1.2)?
It's mentioned on the propel bundle readme, but didn't find any example of how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this:

```
TableQuery::create()->where("match(column) against('+text' in boolean mode)")->find();
```

If anyone found a better solution, please let me know.